# sfntly won't compile via cmake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I try to compile [sfntly](https://github.com/googlei18n/sfntly/) with cmake for Visual Studio 2010 and/or 2015.
The project files are created, but Visual Studio gives me this error message:

```
Error   1   error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/Werror' E:\git\sfntly\cpp\Build\cl  sfntly
```

I think this is because of this part of the CMakeList.txt:

```
set(GCC_OR_CLANG ((CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang") OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX))
    ...
if(GCC_OR_CLANG)
      add_definitions(-D__wur=__attribute__\(\(warn_unused_result\)\) -Wall -Werror -fno-exceptions)
    endif(GCC_OR_CLANG)
```

CMAKE steps into the GCC/CLANG block and adds GCC specific compiler flags, which Visual Studio of course doesn't know.

The project files contain these additional options:

```
<AdditionalOptions> /Zm1000 -g -fno-inline -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-builtin -Werror -fno-exceptions %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with the cmake file?!

Comment: The set command cannot handle "((CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang") OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX))" arguments. Anything passed to the set command is interpreted as strings. These arguments are intended for the if command and you would set GCC_OR_CLANG variable to TRUE if it does evaluate as such.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work, but the project won't compile anyway ... several other exceptions ... will try gcc now ...